# MST: Reverse-delete algorithm

Tags: proof, minimum-spanning-tree

Reverse-delete algorithm: Start with a graph containing all of the edges. Then repeatedly go through the edges in decreasing order of weight. For each edge, check if deleting that edge will disconnect the graph; if not, delete it.

How do I prove that this algorithm computes the MST?

Answer (score 0):

Proof: First, we show that the algorithm produces a spanning tree. This is because the graph is given connected at the beginning and, when deleting edges in the nonincreasing order, only the most expensive edge in any cycle is deleted, which does eliminate the cycles but not disconnect the graph, resulting in a connected graph containing no cycle at the end. To show that the obtained spanning tree is an MST, consider any edge removed by the algorithm. It can be observed that it must lie on some cycle (otherwise removing it would disconnect the graph)and it must be the most expensive one on it (otherwise retaining it would violate the cycle property). Hence, the“Reverse Delete” algorithm produces an MST.

in *WANG, Xiaochun; WANG, Xiali; WILKES, D. Mitchell. A divide-and-conquer approach for minimum spanning tree-based clustering. IEEE Transactions on Knowledge and Data Engineering, 2009, 21.7: 945-958.*